# Maven profile - How to run plugin once for parent and more for modules?

Tags: maven, plugins, module, profile

I'm a little puzzled by my Jenkins output.

Job on Jenkins: (shortened pom.xml at the bottom)

```
mvn deploy -Pprofile1
```

All my plugins will run 4 times:

- parent/pom.xml
- parent/module1/pom.xml
- parent/module2/pom.xml
- parent/module3/pom.xml

I need:

- **first-maven-plugin**: only run **once** in the parent pom.xml
- **second-maven-plugin**: run for **every** pom.xml

Why:

- first-maven-plugin: will run in phase:initialize --> rather long cleanup operation. Don't want this 4 times
- second-maven-plugin: will run in phase:package --> necesaary for all pom's.

Parent pom.xml

```
<project ...>

    <groupId>com.test.parent</groupId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>parent</name>

    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
        <module>module3</module>
    </modules>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile1</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.test.plugin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>first-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <execution>
                            <id>execution1</id>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>doit</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.test.plugin2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>second-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <execution>
                            <id>another</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>goforit</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: do these two plugins have any `skip` option?

Comment: The plugins don't have a skip option. They are generic, since they can run on multiple projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if you define a plugin in the parent which is inherited to all children than it is exactly behaving as you wished which means it is executing on every pom (or in other word on every module doesn't matter if it is a child or not).

The problem of your plugins is that they handle the use cases not very good. Cause you are saying the first one `first-maven-plugin` should run only on root level (Apart from that i don't understand what you mean by cleanup operation...removing target folder?)

And the second plugin `second-maven-plugin` should run for all pom's? Which is not very accurate cause do you mean by pom all child modules which having packaging `pom`? But i assume you mean all children which have packaging `jar`?

Apart from the above i'm not sure if the usage of your profile is only based on the lack of handling the use cases correct.

The result of the above i would conclude you need to change the implementation of your plugins.

If you like having a plugin run only on the root level of such a multi module structure this can handle in a very simple way in your plugin like this:

```java
public void execute()
    throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException
{

    if (mavenProject.isExecutionRoot()) {

    } else {

    }

 ..
```

By using the above your plugin can decide if it is running on root level or not.

So your `first-maven-plugin` can use the following:

```java
public void execute()
    throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException
{

    if (!mavenProject.isExecutionRoot()) {
       getLog().info("Not running at root level");
       return;  
    } 
    // here the time consuming operations        
 ..
```

And your `second-maven-plugin` to do the oposite:

```java
public void execute()
    throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException
{

    if (mavenProject.isExecutionRoot()) {
       getLog().info("Not running at root level");
       return;  
    } 
    // here the operation on the childs.
 ..
```

The behaviour can be improved via the following:

```java
public void execute()
    throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException
{

    if (!mavenProject.isExecutionRoot()) {
       getLog().debug("Not running at root level");
       return;  
    } 

    if ("pom".equals(project.getPackaging())) {
        getLog().debug("Ignoring pom packaging.");
        return;
    }
    // ..now the operations you would like to do...
```

So if you have several levels of module hierarchy you can ignore the `pom` packaging parts or other parts etc.

And last but not least. What do your plugins archive?

Answer (score 14):

You can use `<inherited>false</inherited>` in the first plugin configuration. So it will only run in parent pom execution.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.test.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>first-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <execution>
                <id>execution1</id>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>doit</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.test.plugin2</groupId>
            <artifactId>second-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <execution>
                <id>another</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>goforit</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1671175

Comment: Why this is not the approved answer?